# C# -Last edited Textbox not being saved to database

Tags: c#, sql, textbox, save

I have a C# program that is used for data entry and retrieval from a SQL Database.  Generally it works very well however there is a saving error I am trying to get to the bottom of.  It happens under this specific circumstance.

I update data in a bound textbox.
without leaving the textbox I then press the save button.

When I do this the data in the the bound textbox is not saved to the SQL Database.

This is the program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace Labassist2017
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    //Declare entity objects
    //____________________________________________________________________________________________
    public Lab_Assistant_backendEntities Database_Backend;
    public DbSet Sample_Register;
    public DbSet Product;

    //____________________________________________________________________________________________

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Load_Data();
    }
    public void Load_Data()
    {
        Database_Backend = new Lab_Assistant_backendEntities();
        Sample_Register = Database_Backend.Sample_Register;
        Sample_Register.Load();
        sample_RegisterBindingSource.DataSource = Sample_Register.Local;
        Product = Database_Backend.Products;
        Product.Load();
        productBindingSource.DataSource = Product.Local;
    }
    private void Link_To_Form()
    {

    }

    private void sample_RegisterBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Save();

    }
    public void Save()
    {
        Database_Backend.SaveChanges();

    }
}
}
```

the data is saved under the following circumstance.

I update data in a bound textbox.
I leave the textbox and then press the save button.

Clarification: when I say leave I mean that I press tab and exit the textbox so that it no longer has focus.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Hello! Please read with carefull: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :). Also, could you post some code ?

Comment: what do you mean by leaving the textbox, provide the code you are using to save the data and also the event handler. areyou sure you are using the button clicked event handler?

Comment: Hi Mate,  I press tab and leave the textbox so that it no longer has focus.  if I change the text within it and do not move focus to another object the data is not saved.

Answer (score 0):

What I needed to do was call .EndEdit() in my save method.